# Nuxt: using `v-model` on component with `<script setup>` breaks regular `<script>`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

In a Nuxt3 project, I'm using `v-model` on a component. According to the Vue docs, this is how to do it:

In the parent component:

```
<MyInput v-model="myData" placeholder="My placeholder" />
```

In the child component

```
<template>
  <div class="my-input">
    <input :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    placeholder: {
      type: String
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.placeholder)
  }
}
</script>
```

The Vue docs say I should be able to include both the `<script setup>` and the `<script>` tags within the same file. However, it's causing breaking errors. So long as the `<script setup>` tag remains, the console log returns `undefined`. If I remove the `<script setup>` tag, the console log returns `My placeholder`. Maybe this approach doesn't work within Nuxt? Any ideas?

Comment: It can be combined, but I think it's better to use one script tag that handles everything. Additionally, I don't see why you should use defineProps and props:  altogether when you can define it the old way (the bottom part) or the composition way (the top part)

Comment: This put my on the right trail. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could directly bind your attributes to the input:

```
<template>
  <div class="my-input">
    <input v-bind="$attrs" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This approach does fix the breaking errors, however, it also has a strange side effect of limiting the input's value to a single character, which doesn't display in the input itself.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `<script setup>` tag wasn't necessary after all, and all I had to do was define `modelValue` in the props of my regular script:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: null
    ...
```

Then I could delete the `<script setup>` tag altogether, and `v-model` binds as expected between the parent and the child components.